Odd error: cannot open source file "internal/e_os.h" (dependency of "string")
So I've got a c++ project I'm working on and I'm including openssl source from a cmake. The code working fine and I can compile and link to it without issue. Its the intellisense that is not working in the editor.
But now I have an issue in VSCode where most intilisense isn't working because of the cannot open source file "internal/e_os.h" (dependency of "string") error.
This issue is I have no idea why it's looking for internal/e_os.h and not openssl/e_os.h as the latter exists and the former does not. I've searched my whole system (MacOS) and there are plenty of e_os.h files, but all in a openssl directory, not an internal directory.
My .c_cpp_properties.json file is simple and it works for all the other cmake dependancies:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "engine",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/_deps/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/_deps/openssl-install/include/"
            ],
            "cppStandard": "c++20"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Not sure it matters but here is the openssl bit from my cmake files:
#
# OpenSSL
#

set(OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/openssl-src)
set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/openssl-install)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)
set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/config)
set(OPENSSL_LIB_SSL ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a)
set(OPENSSL_LIB_CRYPTO ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a)

if(NOT EXISTS ${OPENSSL_LIB_SSL} OR NOT EXISTS ${OPENSSL_LIB_CRYPTO})
  message("-- OpenSSL Not Found")
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps)
  ExternalProject_Add(
    OpenSSL
    SOURCE_DIR ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
    GIT_TAG openssl-3.3.2
    USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
      ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND}
      --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
      --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    TEST_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
    INSTALL_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
  )
  set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES ${OPENSSL_LIB_SSL} ${OPENSSL_LIB_CRYPTO})
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
else()
  message("-- OpenSSL Found")
endif()

add_library(OpenSSL::SSL STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL)
add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::Crypto OpenSSL)

How can I get my intellisense working again?

@JaMiT - Clarified, its the intellisense that is not working in the editor.

Is there a reason you aren't just letting the cmake plugin configure intellisense for you?

Two stars (**) means that VSCode specifies as include directory every subdirectory of directory build/_deps/. Some of these subdirectories could contain internal headers of a subproject, which are included only by that subproject in quoted form (like #include "foo.h") or with directory part (#include <bar/foo.h>). If some other project uses regular #include <foo.h>, then intellisense would think that it includes the improper header. I don't find interesting debugging of which header file is included incorrectly because of extra include directories.
